# Upload images with Uikit 2 + Laravel

Tags: laravel, upload, uikit

I have the basic script Uikit 2 for upload images and it don't upload images on public images directory. Why?

**upload.blade.php**

```
<form id="upload" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="upload-drop" class="uk-placeholder">
        <i class="uk-icon-upload uk-icon-large"></i>Select files<input id="upload-select" name="files[]" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
    </div>
    <div id="progressbar" class="uk-progress uk-hidden">
        <div class="uk-progress-bar" style="width: 0%;">...</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
$(function(){

    var progressbar = $("#progressbar"),
        bar         = progressbar.find('.uk-progress-bar'),
        settings    = {

            action: '{{ route('upload') }}', // upload url
            allow : '*.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)', // allow only images
```

.
.
.

routes file:

```
Route::post('/upload',['as' => 'upload', 'uses' => 'upload@upload']);
```

controller file **upload.php**:

```
class upload extends Controller
{
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $images = $request->file('files');
        foreach($images as $key => $image) {
            $filename = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move(public_path().'/images',$filename);
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to upload an array of files you should use files method instead file method:

```
$images = $request->files('files');
```

Comment: Thanks! but the upload of images still doesn't work. I think, could it be that the action is incorrect?

Comment: i see , you didn't put  form action attribute ,put your upload link

Comment: <form id="upload" action="{{ route('upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  It still doesn't work.

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: update upload route :Route::post('upload','upload@upload')->name('upload');

Comment: This is same route. The error 419 is resolved by csrf_token but now appear error 500 Internal server error. I have changed the permissions of the images 777 folder but the same error appear...

Comment: you should put the csrf field {{csrf_field()}} inside form