# Only returns an array value. Array inside Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, foreach

I have this script for upload images, and I upload several images and get only one value:

**In PHP/Laravel:**

```
if ($request->hasFile('files')) {
        $images = $request->file('files');
        $array=[];
        foreach($images as $key => $image) {
            $filename = rand(1,99).'nameimage.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $array[] = $filename;
                //upload images
        }
    return response()->json($array);
    }
```

**In script:**

```
$.each(response, function (k,v){
    console.log('Position: '+k+'. Value: '+v);
});
```

Result, for example: 'Position: 0. Value: 76nameimage.jpg ,
Why?

Comment: What do you trying to achieve?

Comment: I try to upload the images and then show them

Comment: Show us your form, many files need to have multipart/form-data on the form.

Comment: On this url you can see method upload images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886986/upload-images-with-uikit-2-laravel

Comment: check on your input file , make sure it has multiple tag and also the name should be files[]

Comment: If I pass an array manually, if it works. It seems that the problem is in foreach?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this manually;

```
if ($request->hasFile('files')) {
        $images = $request->file('files');
        //$array=[];
        foreach($images as $key => $image) {
            $filename = rand(1,99).'nameimage.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //$array[] = $filename;
                //upload images
        }

    $array=array('1.jpg','2.jpg');
    return response()->json($array);
    }


$.each(response, function (k,v){
    console.log('Position: '+k+'. Value: '+v);
});
```

It works fine, but can the problem be an array inside foreach?
What's the solution?